# Como faço para uma janela não ser fechada? PySimpleGUI

Tags: python

Preciso desativar as opções da janela feita no PySimpleGUI e possibilitar o fechamento somente se acertar a senha numa caixa de texto.

meu codigo:

```
sg.theme('DarkRed')
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Senha'), sg.Input(key='senha', password_char='*')],
    [sg.Button('Liberar')]
]


janela = sg.Window('', layout)

while True:
    eventos, valores = janela.read()
    if eventos == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        Mbox('Titulo', 'Você não pode fechar', 0)
        continue     
    if eventos == 'Liberar':
        if valores ['senha'] == '123456':
            Mbox('Titulo', 'Liberado', 0)
            break
        
        else:
            Mbox('Titulo', 'Senha errada', 0)
```

Abaixo do `sg.WINDOW_CLOSED` eu já tentei colocar um `continue` ou um `pass` mas não funcionou.

Alguma forma de desativar a função, esconder ou fazer o programa abrir toda hora que for fechado?

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isto, você pode adicionar o método `enable_close_attempted_event=True` na sua variável `janela`, exemplo:

```py
janela = sg.Window('', layout, enable_close_attempted_event=True)
```

O recurso retornará um evento de confirmação de tentativa de fechamento da janela ao invés de fechá-la, exibindo uma mensagem personalizada e a janela continuará ativa. Então, adicione a verificação do evento na tentativa de fechamento da janela:

```py
if eventos in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, sg.WINDOW_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT):
   Mbox('Titulo', 'Você não pode fechar', 0)
```

Não se esqueça de terminar seu código com `janela.close()` para não gerar nenhum erro ao finalizar a estrutura de repetição e fechar a janela.

Mais sobre o método Window Close Confirmation [Aqui](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#:%7E:text=Window%20Close%20Confirmation)

Comment: Obrigado!! Deu certinho, vou ler mais sobre esse método